# Memory controller unclaimed in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, hardware, ram

On typing `sudo lshw -c memory` I get a memory UNCLAIMED:

```
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
   description: Memory controller
   product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   version: 21
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:df424000-df427fff
```

Is this something I have to worry about. How do I go about resolving the issue?

And upon resolving how would this improve my device performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a similar result on my server running `sudo lshw -c memory`:

```
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Atom Processor C3000 Series Power Management Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df570000-df573fff
```

And this is on an embedded Intel Atom server motherboard which is 100% supported.

I guess this only serves to show the specs and address space of the power management controller (PMC) - which is oddly also labeled "Memory controller".

So this is absolutely nothing to worry about, enjoy your fully operational Ubuntu system.